# Retain COM Registration After Uninstaller Runs on Development Box

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, com, vb6, installation

I was tasked with building a C# 4.0 application that leverages an old VB6 COM component to integrate with another old VB6 application. The component was built strictly for this integration, and is deployed by my application.

I built an installer for my C# application using Visual Studio Setup project, and added that COM component to the list of deployed files. Installer auto registers/unregisters the component beautifully.

However, the issue I have now is that after uninstalling the application on my development box I can't debug the application without registering the COM component again by hand since the uninstall unregistered it. I'm not implying the uninstall shouldn't unregister the COM component. I'm just trying to figure out a better way of making sure we can still build and test both the application and installer on our development boxes without this inconvenience.

P.S. I tried using a `DllImport`, but it never finds the entry point. From what I understand from research you can't really use a `DllImport` on a COM component. I hope I didn't miss something.

Comment: While I don't doubt you, you will get more responses with a better title.

Comment: I suggest stay away from COM interop, if possible.

Comment: Your title is meaningless. It  should have something to say that refers to the content of your question instead of being a whine or complaint. Please edit to improve it. It helps get answers sooner, and improves the usefulness of the question for future readers or those searching the site. (It would help if you would do less storytelling and more statement of useful information, too. "Ok, let me tell you a story.." isn't too meaningful either.) Thanks.

Comment: Why don't you just write a post-build on your app project that unregister/register the dll?

Comment: @JonB, thanks friend, you're right, I'll change it now.

Comment: @KenWhite, it was less of a whine and more of being sarcastic. But I realize what you're saying and thank you, I've changed it to better reflect the need.

Comment: @KenWhite, and while I stated it was a story to add some color to question, it was in fact information necessary to the history of the problem (at least I thought it was). Generally speaking most questions never contain enough information for us to discern what the developer has already been through or is even **trying** to do.

Comment: @BigM: The title is much better. Thanks. :-) The narrative wasn't terrible, but adding the storytelling style made it a little more difficult to pick out the pertinent parts. Not a big deal, which is why I made it a parenthetical aside rather than the gist of my comment. Again, it makes it more difficult for people searching for something to see if the question is actually something that matches what they're looking for with their search.

Comment: What about a pre-build task that checks to see if the COM component is registered, and registers it if it's not?

Comment: @KenWhite, I'm starting to like the idea of pre/post build tasks. However, how do I check if it's already registered?

Comment: Check `HKLM\Software\Classes` or `HKCU\Software\Classes` to see if there's an entry there for your GUID. You can just see what registry entry is created when you install your component. To see if it's installed, check for the existence of that entry; if it's there, do nothing, and if it's not create the entry. I don't have code handy, but it shouldn't be hard to do. (Famous last words? <g>) The alternative is to actually try and create an instance of the component and catch the exception (`COMException`).

Comment: Testing the installer on a clean machine is probably a better option :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're pretty much doing the right thing and the installer *has* to unregister the COM component unless you want to encounter some really problematic effects on customers machines.

Unfortunately there isn't much you can do apart from maybe writing a simple CMD file to re-register the COM component after you tested the installer.

Comment: I was thinking a CMD file may be the way to go too.